# Show that the trajectory of the solution $ x(t),y(t))$ is contained in the curve $E_{0}$. (Non-Linear Systems, ODE)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

I've been visiting this site for years to solve doubts, and this is my first question it's about something that's almost totally new to me.

We have the autonomous system $x'=y$ and $y'=x^3-x$ (pendulum).
And the following question:
Let $(x(t),y(t))$ be a $(C^1)$ class) solution of the nonlinear system, with $t=0$ given by $(xo,yo)$. Show that the trajectory $(x(t),y(t))$ must be contained on the curve:
$E_{0}=\dfrac{1}{2}y^{2}-\dfrac{1}{4}(x^{2}-1)^{2}, E_{0}$ its constant.

I'm very confused about this exercise, because i don't know what to do with the curve $E_0$ if it's constant!.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we set

$E(x, y) = \dfrac{1}{2}y^2 - \dfrac{1}{4}(x^2 - 1)^2, \tag 1$

we can then express $E(x, y)$ along *any* (sufficiently smooth, say $C^1$) curve

$\gamma(t) = (x(t), y(t)) \tag 2$

as

$E(\gamma(t)) = E(x(t)), y(t)) = \dfrac{1}{2}y^2(t) - \dfrac{1}{4}(x^2(t) - 1)^2; \tag 3$

along such a curve we may compute $dE/dt$:

$\dfrac{dE(\gamma(t))}{dt} = \dfrac{dE(x(t), y(t))}{dt} = \dfrac{\partial E(x(t), y(t))}{\partial x} x'(t) +  \dfrac{\partial E(x(t), y(t))}{\partial y} y'(t); \tag 4$

we have

$\dfrac{\partial E(x, y)}{\partial x} = -\dfrac{1}{2}(x^2 - 1)(2x) = -x(x^2 - 1), \tag 5$

and

$\dfrac{\partial E(x, y)}{\partial y} = y; \tag 6$

if we assume that

$\gamma'(t) = (x'(t), y'(t)) = (y, x^3 - x), \tag 7$

we see that

$\dfrac{dE(\gamma(t))}{dt} =\dfrac{\partial E(x(t), y(t))}{\partial x} x'(t) +  \dfrac{\partial E(x(t), y(t))}{\partial y} y'(t)$
$= -x(t)(x^2(t) - 1)y(t) + y(t)(x^3(t) - x(t))$
$= -x^3(t)y(t) + x(t)y(t) + y(t)x^3(t) - y(t)x(t) = 0; \tag 8$

thus $E(t) = E_0$ is constant along the curves $\gamma(t)$, and from this we furthur conclude that $\gamma(t) = (x(t), y(t))$ is contained in the curve

$\dfrac{1}{2}y^2 - \dfrac{1}{4}(x^2 - 1)^2 = E_0. \tag 9$

Comment: Thank you so much! with this I can continue studying, i've been trapped on this problem for hours!

Comment: @Castle.F:  No problem, glad to help out.  You know you can "accept" my answer if you like, right?

Comment: i will, but i have a doubt!, in (8) you wrote the partial y-derivative of E as x-x^3 and it's x^3-x, or i'm missing something?

Comment: @Castle.F:  gang on and I'll check!

Comment: @Castle.F:  OK, now check it .  The $y$ derivative of $E$ is $y$, but I had $y'$ sign-reversed.  I think it's OK now.  Thanks for catching my error!

Comment: Thank you very much sir!

Comment: @Castle.F:  You are very welcome, and thanks for the "acceptance"!